# MassTransit Xml Deserialization with xml containing attributes

Tags: xml, deserialization, masstransit

Earlier I asked a Question on how to Deserialize an xml message (send wit ActiveMq).
I missed the fact that you can use UseRawXmlSerializer()if MassTransit.NewtonSoft was included.

Now I could Deserialize simple messages like:

```
<event><wqid>1</wqid><event>
```

```
[JsonObject("event")]   
public class WorkQueueOrderEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("wqid")]
    public int WorkQueueId { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I am not getting the event in this format.
I am receiving it like:

```
<event wqid="22"/>
```

It does run but I end up with 0 in the WorkQueueId.

I tried [XmlAttribute("wqid")] but that did not work.

Comment: See NewtonSoft para at https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/integrations/serialization

Comment: @jdweng I tried the UseRawXmlSerializer and it works, except for my scenario described above. Your link does not give a solution for my problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :-)
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm

An xml attribute translates into "@".
So all I needed to do is adapt:

```
[JsonObject("event")]   
public class WorkQueueOrderEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("@wqid")]             <====== added @
    public int WorkQueueId { get; set; }
}
```